# Python and Excel take cell value by its name instead that by its coordinate

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can I take a cell value with Python 2.7 by accessing cell's name, created in Excel, rather than giving coordinates?

In this case by accessing "Surname" instead of D8:

IMG: http://www.hosting.universalsite.org/image-excel-EBA2_58B5BC06.png

Comment: Can you post the code you're using instead of images?

Comment: `openpyxl` supports [defined names](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/defined_names.html).

Comment: I have no code I can show right now.

Answer (score 1):

[`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html) supports [defined names](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/defined_names.html):

Example from docs:

> ```
> my_range = wb.defined_names['my_range']
> # if this contains a range of cells then the destinations attribute is not None
> dests = my_range.destinations # returns a generator of (worksheet title, cell range) tuples
>
> cells = []
> for title, coord in dests:
>     ws = wb[title]
>     cells.append(ws[coord])
> ```

Assuming `'Surname'` applies to only one cell you could extract it as follows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='your_workbook.xlsx')
title, coord = next(wb.defined_names['Surname'].destinations)
result = wb[title][coord].value
```

Comment: And I got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 102, in <module>
    title, coord = next(wb.defined_names['Surname'])
TypeError: DefinedName object is not an iterator`

Comment: If I run `my_range = wb.defined_names['Surname']` it works and i get:
Parameters:
comment=None, help=None, localSheetId=None, customMenu=None, functionGroupId=None, publishToServer=None, attr_text='Sheet1!$D$18', workbookParameter=None, hidden=None, function=None, description=None, statusBar=None, shortcutKey=None, vbProcedure=None, xlm=None, name='Surname'

Still I need to know how to call the coordinates, now

Comment: I should have written `title, coord = next(wb.defined_names['Surname'].destinations)` rather than `title, coord = next(wb.defined_names['Surname'])`. Updating answer.